# Transfer value from Node JS to Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

i am trying to transfer an argument from node js to Input Tag in my Jade page,
here is my code:

Node js :

```
res.render("index" ,{title: userName});
```

Jade Page (which called 'index') :

```
.input
    input(type='text', value= #{title} ,  maxlength='15')
```

What i am doing wrong here ?

Here is my error message :

> 48|         input(type='text', value= #{title} ,  maxlength='15')
>
> Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>       at Function (native)

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an escaped string interpolation like described here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/
This doesn't work as attribute, you have to use buffered code, like described here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/

It would look like this:

```
// escaped code
.input
    input(type='text', value= title ,  maxlength='15')
// unescaped code
.input
    input(type='text', value!= title ,  maxlength='15')
```

If you want to use an object for your attributes, you can handle it with `input&attributes(object)`, like descibed here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes

Node.js

```
res.render("index" ,{
   input: {
      type: 'text',
      title: userName, 
      maxlength: '15',
      name: 'myInputName'
   }
});
```

Jade:

```
.input
    input&attributes(input)
```

Result of both:

```
<div class="input">
   <input type="text" value="username" maxlength="15" name="myInputName" />
</div>
```

Here is a workinh Pen without Node as example in Jade:
http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/oLPGJy

Comment: @Tal ... Then you are doing something wrong in you app.js or your node script. My example works perfect. Here is a profed pen: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/oLPGJy

Comment: Yes, there was something  wrong in my script . ur answeer is correct. thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Would it just work as is: `value=title`?

```
.input
    input(type='text', value=title ,  maxlength='15')
```